# jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>

Tags: shell, variables, syntax-error, jq

```sh
cat explorer/connection-profile/test-network.json | jq ".organizations.Org1MSP.adminPrivateKey.path |= 44ab"

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.organizations.Org1MSP.adminPrivateKey.path|=44ab                                               
jq: 1 compile error
```

but it works fine with

```sh
cat explorer/connection-profile/test-network.json | jq ".organizations.Org1MSP.adminPrivateKey.path |= 44"
```

Why?

Actually I am trying to use

```sh
cat explorer/connection-profile/test-network.json | jq ".organizations.Org1MSP.adminPrivateKey.path |= ${PRIV_KEY}"
```

where the ${PRIV_KEY} is 44ab..._sk

Comment: Try  `... |  jq '.organizations.Org1MSP.adminPrivateKey.path |= "44ab"'`

Comment: @jas Yeah, this works fine, but actually I want change 44ab with a variable, so I cant use double quote ('') outside this string. ^ ^ thanks anyway

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can assign a string to a variable that can be used inside a `jq` filter:

```sh
PRIV_KEY="44ab..._sk"
jq --arg path "$PRIV_KEY" '.organizations.Org1MSP.adminPrivateKey.path |= $path' explorer/connection-profile/test-network.json
```

This method is safer than trying to embed an expanded shell variable directly in the filter string because `jq` will properly handle arbitrary values instead of choking on things like quotes (Or their absence).

---

Note that `jq` takes filenames as arguments after the filter expression; no need for `cat` here (Unless that's standing in for `curl` or something, of course, and you're not using an existing file)

Comment: It works! You are so kind. ^ ^ Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

did you try this , i fixed the same error by setting the expression between '' and the values between ""

```
cat explorer/connection-profile/test-network.json | jq '.organizations.Org1MSP.adminPrivateKey.path |= "44ab"'
```